# Remove space After the horizontal line in phpWord

Tags: php, phpword

This is an issue I came across when using phpWord:
I have added 2 horizontal lines then added some texts between them. But it always take an extra line before the text. Can you please let me know how to remove that blank space line:
codeblock:

```
$aLineSty = array('weight'=> 1, 'width' => 720, 'height'=> 0, 'color'=> '000');
$oSection->addLine($aLineSty);
$_sTextInsideLine = 'bla bladshfsdfh dfhdsf sfhsf sfhs bla bla......';
$oSection->addText($_sTextInsideLine, array('size'=> 9.5), $aBodyPara);
$oSection->addLine($aLineSty);
```

it looks like:
[image]

I have posted this question already in Github but didn't get any response :
[Remove space After the horizontal line #712](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/712)

Comment: Is there an update regarding this @hari?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please go through https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/phpword/latest/phpword.pdf

This may help you.

Comment: I already checked this and http://phpword.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ also. But these documentation does not solve the current issue